# Electric water heater overheating

Tags: hot-water

My electric hot water tank is putting out very hot water. Can I find out which  thermostat is bad without an amp meter? The top one clicks off at a high temp, and the lower at a lower temp.

Comment: There is such a thing as a shift key on your keyboard to support insertion of capital letters and punctuation into your posting.

Comment: A volt meter would do, or if you had a spare socket and a bit of wire, you could use a lightbulb.

Comment: Turn off every other large power consumer in your house, and then watch the main electric meter while you adjust the thermostats.

Answer (score 1):

So, did you try turning the thermostats down? And did the WH continue to heat?  Usually the coils make some noise as they heat the water. Like a pot on stove.

Try dialing them up and down. If there is one that never shuts off then that one is broke.

Good luck!

Comment: The easy things usually get overlooked+